# Replacing spaces in string after input?

Tags: c, loops, linked-list, scanf

In the following code when the user enters a space at address the program falls into a infinite loop?

example: street,town, city would crash the program, how can I replace the spaces with a ','? or at least stop this from happening

```
printf("\nEnter address:\n");
scanf("%s", newNode->address);
printf("\nEnter department:\n");
scanf("%d", &newNode->depart);
while(validDate == 0){
printf("\nEnter Data Of Join(dd/mm/yy):\n");
if (scanf("%d%*[-/. ]%d%*[-/. ]%d", &newNode->day, &newNode->mounth, &newNode->year) != 3){
    printf("Wrong format! Please enter a date and exclude the slashes! eg. 15 01 95");
}
else{
    // break the loop
    validDate = 1;
}
}// date validation end
```

Comment: regarding the calls to scanf(): 1) the "%s" should have length modifier, so the input buffer is not overrun.   2) the returned value (not the parameters) should be checked to assure the operation was successful 3) this: "%d%*[-/. ]%d%*[-/. ]%d" should be: "%d/%d/%d"  This will input the three date variables, just like the prompt requested

Comment: You should read the date as a string (complete line) then parse the date from that string.

Comment: Replace all `scanf(...)` with `char buf[100]; fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); if(sscanf(buf, ...`

Comment: scanf() stops at white space (' ' \t \n)  which is why the code stays in a loop.  Simply use a data, as the prompt requested and it will work correctly

Answer (score 0):

try

```
gets()
```

instead of scanf(). The scanf will stop reading the input when it encounters a space character. And the remaining string data will stay in the input buffer and that may causing the issue.